# how to post data in ios objective c using NSURLSESSION AND NSJSONSerialization?

Tags: objective-c

I want data in json format, 
example :- 
      [{
         name : one;
       },
       {
         name : two;
       }];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to post data in NSmutableURL Request. I will Provide Source code to you, Hope it will work for You.

```
NSString *strurl=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@insert_comment.php",BASE_URL];

NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tip_id=%@&user_id=%@&comment=%@",[self.SeletedTipData objectForKey:@"id"],[userinfo objectForKey:@"id"],CommentTextFiled.text];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strurl]];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
if (postData == nil){
    UIAlertView *invalidLogin = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Something Wrong" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [invalidLogin show];

}
else{
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];
    /*specify the request type */
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    /* set the data to be posted on server into body for "POST"*/
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

    [[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

        NSMutableDictionary *dataResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
        NSLog(@"dataResponds=%@",dataResponse);
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if ([[dataResponse objectForKey:@"status"] isEqualToString:@"true"]) {
               NSLog(@"dataResponds=%@",dataResponse);
            }else if ([[dataResponse objectForKey:@"status"] isEqualToString:@"false"]){

                [CommanFunction displayAlertView:@"Something Wrong"];
            }

        });
    }] resume];
}
```

i sure this source code will help you.

Comment: yes, it is working for me, Thank you So Much. @sumit